# Kotlin functions inside a const

Tags: kotlin

I am learning kotlin, and want to know how to add functions to a const,

here the JS example...

```
function suma (a, b){
    return a + b
}

console.log("sua suma::", suma(2,3))

function multiplica (a, b){
    return a * b
}

console.log("sua multiplik::", multiplica(2,3))

const operations = {
    suma,
    multiplica
}

console.log ("sum of first class::", operations.suma(2,3))
console.log ("mult of first class::", operations.multiplica(2,3))
```

so how do I achieve the same on Kotlin?

Here what I have tried:

```
fun suma(a: Int, b: Int): Int{
    return a + b
}

fun multiplica (a: Int, b: Int): Int{
    return a * b
}

const operations = {
    suma(),
    multiplica()
}

fun main() {
    println("sua suma:: ${suma(2, 3)}")
    println("sua multiplica:: ${multiplica(2, 3)}")

    println("sua multiplica:: ${operations.multiplica(2,3)}")
}
```

Comment: Rather than trying to find a strict equivalent to Javascript, you'd probably get a better answer if you post what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using `object` keyword, like following:

```kotlin
fun suma(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return a + b
}

fun multiplica(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return a * b
}

fun main() {
    
    val operations = object {
        val _suma = ::suma
        val _multiplica = ::multiplica
    }

    println("sua suma:: ${operations._suma(2, 3)}")
    println("sua multiplica:: ${operations._multiplica(2, 3)}")
}
```

The only disadvantage is that you have to choose a name for `operations.XXXXX` that is different from the name of referenced function: note `var _suma` vs `fun suma`. Otherwise the compiler will consider it recursive problem

Answer (score 2):

"Only Primitives and String are allowed" for const

The operator you're looking for is :: (Double colon)

An enum example of this is

```
enum class Operations(function: KFunction<Int>) {
    Suma(function = ::suma),
    Multiplica(function = ::multiplica)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but im getting errors... 
"error: expecting member declaration
    Multiplica(function = ::multiplica);"

Comment: @manuelBetancurt Sorry, the enum was missing a comma, it should be Suma(function = ::suma),
    Multiplica(function = ::multiplica) - I've updated the answer for proper formatting

Answer (score 1):

The main issues here are that Kotlin is a statically typed language, and doesn't have the same idea of Objects that can contain arbitrary attributes, like Javascript does.

I'm kinda new to Kotlin, so there may be a better way to do this, but what I'd do is define a Map to do the same sort of thing:

```
fun suma(a: Int, b: Int): Int{
    return a + b
}

fun multiplica (a: Int, b: Int): Int{
    return a * b
}

val operations: Map<String, (a: Int, b:Int) -> Int> = hashMapOf(
        "suma" to ::suma,
        "multiplica" to ::multiplica)

fun main() {
    println("sua suma:: " + operations.get("suma")?.invoke(2, 3))
    println("sua multiplica:: " + operations.get("multiplica")?.invoke(2, 3))
}
```

Result:

```
sua suma:: 5
sua multiplica:: 6
```

Note that `operations` is an immutable Map ('const' kinda) in that its contents can't be changed once it's defined.

The access and having to use `invoke` seems kinda messy. This seems to be due to the fact that a Map can only contain nullable types.  That's the main reason I think there's probably a better way to do this.